# Firebase keeps showing the old package name in google-services.json file

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

`com.myweb.example` was my package name, and it was registered in firebase console.

I changed the package name to `com.example.newweb`, and added a new app in same firebase project with different package name, now when i download `google-services.json` file, it still shows the old package name in it.

Hence app does not connect with firebase project.

However package name does changes in these 2 places. In rest of 4 places it shows old package name in `google-services.json` file.

```
"client_info": { }
"oauth_client": []
```

I need to know why its showing the old `package name` in a new app in firebase console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In google-services.json file contains multiple clients as your apps. so please check the clients key in google-services.json.
this contains all your client apps

```
{
"client": [
{
  "client_info": {
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "******001" // first app package name
    }
  }
},
{
  "client_info": {
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "******002" // second app package name
    }
  }
}
]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, You are right, that was the problem i was facing on that day